# Finite integral involving Bessel Function of the second kind

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

I need to solve the following integral

\begin{equation} 
    \int_{0}^{\infty} Y_1\big(\sigma \cdot (r-a) \cdot \sin(\theta) \big) e^{-\sigma^2 \nu t} d\sigma \end{equation}

where $Y_1(x)$ is the Bessel Function of the second kind. I was unable to solve it directly in Maple. Can anyone help me to solve it?

From the above integral, I want to calculate the following
\begin{equation} 
    \frac{d}{dr} \int_{0}^{\infty} r \ Y_1\big(\sigma \cdot (r-a) \cdot \sin(\theta) \big) \ e^{-\sigma^2 \nu t} \ d\sigma
\end{equation}

So any solution to the above integrals will solve my problem. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Your integral diverges because $Y_1(x)$ behaves like $-2/(\pi x)$ near $x=0$.

Comment: Thank you. 
Still, I am unable to solve the integral from say 1 to $\infty$.

Comment: If the integration limit is not from $0$ to $\infty$, then **almost certainly** there will not be an analytic solution. Integrals involving bessel functions depend heavily on limits of integration.

Comment: That is a good point. Do you know if there is a way to find an approximate solution?

Comment: @Ahmad Perhaps any of the standard numerical integration techniques???